# Uploaded video screen capture using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I need to capture frames of user's uploaded videos. i just came to know that ffmpeg does that.Please provide me detailed installation instruction of ffmpeg on my linux server .i just have info to login into ssh via putty. Also what are the softwares i need to install.does ffmpeg player includes in the installation process.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What is your distro? What formats are you encoding to? By "ffmpeg player" do you mean "ffplay"? What does this have to do with programming? Stack Overflow is limited to questions and answers related to programming.

Comment: i just need to know step by step instructions on how to install ffmpeg on my linux server.

Comment: That is obvious. You already mentioned that but failed to answer any of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the very limited information you provided you may be able to perform a very basic ffmpeg installation using the following:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
$ cd ffmpeg
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

You will need `gcc`, `git`, and `make` as dependencies. `pkg-config` and `yasm` are recommended dependencies.